# Looking for an alternative to DisplayMemberPath for a TextBox or a code work-around

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, custom-controls

Looking at the inheritance hierarchy from which `TextBox` comes, I see that `TextBox` doesn't have a `DisplayMemberPath` property. And this makes sense because it doesn't have Items for an `ItemsSource` to be bound to, and therefore there is no `DisplayMemberPath`. However, I need something like a `DisplayMemberPath` for a `TextBox` or something editable and I am looking for options based on my situation below.

Classes/Views/ViewModels I am working with:

**`Test.cs`** - Code First Entity

```
public class Test : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GasProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

**`GasProfile.cs`** - Code First Entity

```
public class GasProfile : BaseModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double H2O { get; set; }
    public double CO2 { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Test> _tests;
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Test> Tests
    {
        get { return _tests; }
        set
        {

            if (_tests != value)
            {
                _tests = value;
                Notify("Tests");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`TestGasView.xaml`** - View (USerControl)

This is what TestGasView.xaml **looks like now**:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTechnician.Test}"
             DisplayMemberPath="TestName">
             selectedItem="SelectedTest"
    </ListBox>

    <Label Content="H20"/>
    <TextBox></TextBox>
    <Label Content="CO2"/>
    <TextBox></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

This is **what I want** it to look like / behave like (Warning: Broken Code/ Pseudo code):

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTechnician.Test}"
             DisplayMemberPath="TestName"
             SelectedItem="SelectedTest">
    </ListBox>

    <Label Content="H20"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedTest.GasProfile}"
             DiaplayMemberPath="H20"></TextBox>
    <Label Content="CO2"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedTest.GasProfile}"
             DiaplayMemberPath="CO2"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

**`TestGasViewModel.cs`** - ViewModel

Has a property to get/set the SelectedTest.

As you can see, the databinding I want on the `TextBox`es is wrong, as is the placement of `DisplayMemberPath`, but this shows that I am very intent on having the value that is displayed be 1) editable 2) be shown by clicking on a test and binding to the "gas property" on the GasProfile the SelectedTest has a key to.

So my question is, "Is there some property I am missing on a `TextBox` that lets me bind the `Text` property to GasProfile and get the value for the gas I want to display?" If not, perhaps there is some way to create a proxy class that would enable binding something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTechnician.Test}"
             DisplayMemberPath="TestName"
             SelectedItem="SelectedTest">
    </ListBox>

    <Label Content="H20"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedTestGasProfile.H20}"></TextBox>
    <Label Content="CO2"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedTestGasProfile.CO2}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

If its not a "Oh, use this property for the `TextBox`" then I am looking for code suggestions to make the above happen.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot to show that I indeed do have a selected test and FieldGasProfileID (which is what I meant by GasProfile) does have a value:

[image: Selected Test]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedTest.GasProfile.H20}"</TextBox>
<Label Content="CO2"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedTest.GasProfile.CO2}"</TextBox>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: But I thought you couldn't do "Class.Property.Property". Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ethicallogics I just tried it and its not displaying a value. I am wondering if my relationship is set up wrong so that my syntax is not working. A Test should have only one GasProfile, however a GasProfile can have many Tests. What do you think? If not then maybe the syntax is wrong for the binding.

Comment: Yes according to the above code it seems so.If your SelectedTest Binding is working fine then the above one should also work.

Comment: @ethicallogics Please see the edit/screenshot I added. So I do have a SelectedTest, and it is working fine. So I would have thought the syntax you suggested would be pretty much the same as what I have done before.

Comment: I got it ,you have SelectedTest of type Test and this type dont have any GasProfile property.SelectedTest.GasProfile is incorrect.

Comment: You need to rethink about the relationships between Test and GasProfile class.

Comment: @ethicallogics Well this makes sense but the business rule is to have a one-to-many from GasProfile to test. Do you have a suggestion for how to work it so that it does make sense? Would I need a Many-to-Many relationship where Test has an `ObservableCollection<GasProfile> GasProfiles` just like GasProfile currently has an `ObservableCollection<Test> Tests`?

Comment: I think you should have property GasProfile of Type GasProfile in Test class.

Comment: @ethicallogics But what maps GasProfileID property (already on the Test class) to this new property? I have tried something similar where i open a new DbContext and set `value = db.FieldGasProfiles.Find(FieldGasProfileId);` and nothing seems to get set